# Original error: unknown error: Chrome version must be >= 55.0.2883.0

Tags: android, selenium, mobile, appium, hybrid

I am trying to switch view from native to web view.

I run $driver.available_contexts and get `=> ["NATIVE_APP", "WEBVIEW_com.nuffield.classbooking"]` I then try and switch to $driver.set_context("WEBVIEW_com.nuffield.classbooking") and I get

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: An unknown server-side error 
occurred while processing the command. Original error: unknown error: 
Chrome version must be >= 55.0.2883.0
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455517 
(2c6d2707d8ea850c862f04ac066724273981e88f),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.5 
x86_64)
```

Also when I run `$driver.set_context("WEBVIEW")` I get the same error message above

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Updating chrome might resolved issue.

Comment: how does one update the chrome browser version on an emulator?